# Transaction rollback configuration in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

How to configure hibernate for rolling back transactions in the associated tables in case of exceptions? I have a Transaction table and there are associated tables in which data needs to be persisted to but if something goes wrong i want to rollback all of them.

Answer (score 1):

**A transaction is a database feature that  guarantees atomicity.** It's always started and committed or rolled back on the database level.

Using the Hibernate you can **start, commit or rollback the transaction**. (Suppose you have an instance of Hibernate `SessionFactory`)

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        // perform some data changes ...
        session.getTransaction().commit(); // will save all changes 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback(); // will discard all changes
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

**After you start a transaction you can start changing data in different tables.** All changes that have been done in the scope of transaction will be either committed or rolled back.

**Please note**, that when you use Hibernate to start the transaction, **it calls JDBC Driver** under the hood ([see JDBC transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)), and the **driver uses a proper SQL query** to start a transaction (see [PostgreSQL START TRANSACTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-start-transaction.html)).

*You should not manage transactions manually in real projects. Frameworks like [Spring](https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework) provide much more sophisticated declarative transaction management.*